# How get the count of addedfiles in addedfile event?

Tags: dropzone.js

How I can get the total number of addedfiles in addedfile event?

```
uploader.on("addedfile", function(file){

    here - how I can get the total number of addedfiles?

});
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.files` always holds the list of all files that have been dropped.

If you only want to get the files that have been accepted, you can use `this.getAcceptedFiles();`

So to answer your question, use either of those:

```
var totalFileCount = this.files.length;
// or
var totalFileCount = this.getAcceptedFiles().length;
```